# Onclick not toggled off when clicked

Tags: javascript

This toggle function works my drop down as I need to a point. when i clcik my link the menu opens with the overlay. but if i click the link again only the menu closes. I need to change the overlay to none depending on toggle.

```
  function navDeck() {
    "use strict"
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("is-open");
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to see if you clicked edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and created a [mcve] with relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: After your edit, it is impossible to guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using the following

```
  function navDeck() {
    "use strict"
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("is-open");
    var e = document.getElementById("overlay");

       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this.

New css class

```
.open-overlay{
  display:block;
}
```

JS

```
function navDeck() {
    "use strict"
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("is-open");
  document.getElementById("overlay").classList.toggle("open-overlay");
}
```